# SwiftUI animation causes app to crash with AsyncRenderer

Tags: swiftui

I have an animation to represent vibrations, this can play for several minutes. After 2-3 minutes, the app spikes from 30-100% + in CPU before crashing. Here is the animation:

```
ZStack {
ForEach(1..<10, id: \.self) { num in
   Circle()
      .stroke(Color.accentColor, lineWidth: CGFloat(num))
      .scaleEffect(patternManager.animate ? 1.0 : (0.1 * Double(num)))
      .mask {
         RadialGradient(colors: [.black, .clear],
                        center: .center,
                        startRadius: 0.0,
                        endRadius: size.width / 1.8)
      }
   }
   .frame(width: size.width, height: size.width)
   .opacity(patternManager.isVibrating ? 1.0 : 0.0)
   .animation(.linear(duration: 0.5).repeatForever(autoreverses: false),
                       value: patternManager.animate)
}
```

Here is what I am getting back:

> com.apple.SwiftUI.AsyncRenderer (40): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16bc9fff0)
>
> SwiftUI: closure #1 in KitRendererCommon(_:) + 168

Basically, every 0.1 seconds the patternManager.animate is toggled. The issue seems to be purely in the animation as remove the .scaleEffect() line will prevent any issues.

Why would this cause the app to crash?

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue when I interrupt another animation. It was crashing at the start of animation on Xcode 14.0/14.1, but when I updated to Ventura with Xcode 14.2, I was able to cycle through some of animations before it would crash. My issue was: `com.apple.SwiftUI.AsyncRenderer (11): EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

Comment: My sample Swift Playgrounds code crashes on iPhone 14 Pro Simulator (16.2), but doesn't on an iPhone 11 Pro Max with iOS 16.0.2. However, when I integrate the animation into my iOS app, it does crash after cycling through the animation. A different crash: `com.apple.SwiftUI.AsyncRenderer (9): EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1b8c78c7c)`

Comment: I had some conditional logic in my `withAnimation { }` block that was setting a `@State` variable, which may be the culprit with my crashes. I was just trying to loop indices, so I would reset the index, and that seemed to cause the issue. So I use temporary variables for the if/else logic and then only set the final value once inside the `withAnimation` block.  
```withAnimation {
    currentStage = nextStage
    didComplete = shouldComplete
}```

Comment: It seems that the issue comes from some logic inside a `withAnimation{}` block for me too.